# How to get IBM doors health data or information using api or any other way

Tags: ibm-doors

I am new to IBM DOORS and want to create a dashboard in which I need to get data from DOORS.
Please suggest to get the doors health data using api.

Comment: why is this question tagged "websphere"?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to define "health" in DOORS reliably. Perhaps it is sufficient to test whether the port to the Server is open, like
`Test-NetConnection -ComputerName DOORSSERVERNAME -Port 36677 |Format-List -Property TcpTestSucceeded`